# Windows no longer boots, computer goes straight to BIOS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I built myself a PC about 3 years ago.

I5-4670

H87-Plus mobo

Asus GTX 760

Samsung SSD boot drive

Seagate HDD (storage and non-essential programs)

8GB RAM

Corsair RM650 PSU

A few days ago, when I tried to boot it, it opened straight to BIOS instead of starting Windows 7. In the BIOS, I can see all the available hard drives listed correctly. When I try to manually select the proper boot drive, it attempts to boot for 10-20 seconds, then goes back to the BIOS.

I tried to boot from a windows install disk to run a repair, but the repair utility claims that it is incompatible with the version of windows I am running (Win7 Home OEM). Opening a command prompt and running chkdsk reports that it detected a few pieces of free space marked as allocated, but and scheduled them for repair on the next boot (I think it was making fun of me, since there is no next boot). sfc /scannow said it couldn't run while repairs were scheduled and that I should reboot to complete them. Thanks sfc.

I removed both HDDs and took them to work, where I have a working machine. I ran chkdsk on both (it managed to repair the allocated space issue), and sfc on the boot drive reported that the windows installation was clean.

I backed up the data I need from them, and I will go home now, reinstall the hard drives and try to boot. But since nothing really happened, I don't expect it to work.

There appears to be nothing obviously wrong with the hard drives (are there any other tests I should run?). The SSD is well below its write limit (around 30%, as reported by the Samsung SSD wizard). On the other hand, there appears to be nothing obviously wrong with any of the components, since the BIOS reports the proper amount of RAM, the video card seems fine, and the MOBO appears to be functional.

Any ideas as to why it no longer boots? Anything I could try? I am considering just formatting and reinstalling Windows, but I would like to understand why this happened since it would be a pain to just have it happen again after reinstalling.

Comment: "I tried to boot from a windows install disk to run a repair" - So were you using a Windows 7 Home installation disk or something else?

Comment: I used the original install disk that I used to install Windows in the first place (yes, it makes no sense that it would claim to be incompatible, but here I am). When that failed, I tried a Win7 Professional USB key from a friend, with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a recent WIndows update which turns on the "secure boot" option in the BIOS - secure boot is incompatible with Windows 7 (why they would make it an automatic Win7 update? WHO KNOWS?). To fix it, go to the boot menu in the BIOS and set the secure boot tab to "other OS".